# "List object is not callable" error when using Property method in Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using property method in class to get a subset of user's input:

```
class deck:
    def __init__(self, card_list):
        self.cards = card_list
        self.cards_slice = []

    def get_deal_card(self):
        return self.cards_slice

    def set_deal_card(self, count):
        if count > len(self.cards):
            raise Exception("Process failed. Out of index.")
        else:
            self.cards_slice = self.cards.pop(count)

    deal_card = property(get_deal_card, set_deal_card)

d1 = deck([['A',1],['B',1]])
d1.deal_card(0)
```

It returns type error "List object is not callable". I know this error occurs when I previously defined a list with a name that I used somewhere else. However I still can't see what I do wrong in this program.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give the full traceback. Is there a particular reason you aren't using the conventional decorator version of `property`?

Comment: `deal_card` returns a list. What do you think calling it with `deal_card(0)` would accomplish?

Comment: There is no particular reason why i don't use @property here. I thought two methods are equivalent and interchangeably. Is it not?

Comment: Sorry @JimFasarakisHilliard I still don't get it. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: When `d1.deal_card` is encountered `get_deal_card` is triggered which returns `self.cards_slice` (initialized to `[]`). You then call it by using `(0)` after `d1.deal_card` which, essentially, tries to do `[](0)`. That fails  because lists aren't callable.

Comment: `deal_card` is a property, not a function. But you're trying to use it like a function. Use it like a variable instead.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all!